# Log excess returns calculation

Tags: returns, fama-french, log-returns

I need to calculate log excess returns.
I'm given market level monthly total return index, price index and a risk-free rate (from Fama/French 3/5/etc. factors).
I'm not sure whether I'm calculating the log excess returns correctly.

$log\ excess\ return = log\ gross\ return - log\ risk\ free\ rate$

$log\ gross\ return_{t} = log(total\ return\ index_t/price\ index_{t-1}) $ (Campbell-Shiller, 1988)

I assume that FF monthly risk-free rates are not log-transformed, but since there are zeros in RF column, I'm getting `Inf` values for $log\ risk\ free\ rate$.

Should I then calculate gross return on levels, take the difference and then apply log-transformation?

Comment: I don't know what convention FF use for their risk free rate. But if the risk free rate is $r_f$ in conventional terms, the logarithmic rate is $\ln (1+r_f)$. So $r_f=0$ produces 0, not `-Inf`

Comment: The two above should be the same if the returns in the first are ln(1 + linear retiurn).

Comment: @noob2 yes, thanks, that fixes it. Is my overall approach correct?